# GPO Security setting Wired Network (IEEE 802.3) Policies

Tags: active-directory, security, group-policy

My question is regarding group policy security setting (Wired Network (IEEE 802.3) Policies). When I set this setting I cannot see any file generated to store these settings in SYSVOL\sysvol\domainName\guid\Machine\ path. May I know where can I find these settings stored? My requirement is to read and parse those settings to store it in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wired Network policy settings are stored in the Group Policy Container (AD System -> Policies), not the GPT (Sysvol share). You can expose these settings by searching for the "ms-net-ieee-8023-GroupPolicy" object class:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter {objectClass -eq "ms-net-ieee-8023-GroupPolicy"} -Properties *
```

You can also use the ADU&C GUI to find the settings:

```
<domain>/System/Policies/{<GPO-GUID>}/Machine/Microsoft/Windows/IEEE8023/<Wired Network policy name>
```